# How do I get a column to be sort in descending order upon loading?

Tags: jqgrid

I'm wondering how do I get a sorted column in descending order upon loading.  I have seen some questions/answers in stack-overflow but it all depends on the jqGrid configuration.  That I haven't got it to work...  It need to be done locally once the data is received from the server.

Thanks..

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jquery-ui-v1.10.3.themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jqgrid-v4.5.0/ui.multiselect.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jqgrid-v4.5.0/ui.jqgrid.css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/jqgrid-v4.5.0/ui.jqgrid-bio-override.css" />
<script src="../scripts/jquery-ui-v1.10.3/minified/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jqgrid-v4.5.0/ui.multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/jqgrid-v4.5.0/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--<script src="../scripts/jqgrid-v4.5.0/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
<script src="../scripts/jqgrid-v4.5.0/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <% var httpPrefix = (EnvironmentSetting.WebServerEnvironment_DeveloperMachine == true ? "http" : "https"); %>
        <% var urlRandom = new System.Random(5); %>
        <% var httpAdditionalDetailToken = System.DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + System.DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + urlRandom.Next(1000).ToString(); %>
        <% var postQuickQuoteSalePrice = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["QuickQuoteSalePrice"]) == true ? "" : Convert.ToString(Request["QuickQuoteSalePrice"])); %>

        //My Inventory Spreadsheet...
        var jqgridSpreadsheetId = 'MyInventoryJqgrid_Spreadsheet';
        var jqgridPagerId = 'MyInventoryJqgrid_Pager';
        var jqgridGroupColumnHeader = 'MyInventoryJqgrid_GroupColumnHeader';
        var jqgridDialogLinkOptions = 'MyInventoryJqgrid_PopupDialogLinkOptions';
        var jqgridColumnIdStockNumber = 1;
        var jqgridColumnIdVin = 2;
        var jqgridColumnIdInventoryTrackerLocationId = 13;
        var jqgridColumnNameLinks = "Links";
        var jqgridHiddenDialog1 = "";
        //My Inventory Summary Spreadsheet...
        var jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId = 'MyInventorySummaryJqgrid_Spreadsheet';

        //var jqgridData = '{"total":3,"page":1,"records":3,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["73157978","1234","1GTCS149698119451","2009","GMC","Canyon Regular Cab","SLE Pickup 2D 6 ft","34555","4500.00","2013-04-30","0.00","4500.00","14",""]},{"id":2,"cell":["72174115","","1G1JE6SH0C4134329","2012","Chevrolet","Sonic","LTZ Hatchback Sedan 4D","0","100.00","2013-01-14","0.00","100.00","120",""]},{"id":3,"cell":["72167761","Rrrrr","1GNEK13TX1R173136","2001","Chevrolet","Tahoe","Sport Utility 4D","5000","6000.00","2013-01-11","0.00","6000.00","123","San Francisco"]}]}';

        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //My Inventory Spreadsheet...
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //jqGrid Plugin...
        //http://www.trirand.com...
        //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201883/jqGrid-Quick-Tips...  //Useful quick-tip to get up and going fast...
        $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid({
            url: '../websrvc/JqGrid.ashx',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            postData: { WhichJqgridTemplate: '<%=JqqridTools.Template.MyInventory%>', WhichAction: '<%=JqqridTools.Action.Display%>', WebpageQuickQuoteSalePrice: '<%=postQuickQuoteSalePrice%>' },
            colNames: ['Id', 'Stock Number', 'VIN', 'Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Trim', 'Mileage', 'Purchase Price', 'Stock Date', 'Repair Cost', 'Total Cost', 'Days In Inventory', 'Hidden-Inventory-Tracker-Location-Id', 'Inventory Tracker Location', 'Links'],  //Display Text in Column Header...
            colModel: [
                       { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', sorttype: 'int', width: 0, align: 'left', hidden: true, hidedlg: true },  //"hidedlg" is use to hide the hidden column in "Column Chooser"...
                       { name: 'StockNumber', index: 'StockNumber', sorttype: 'text', width: 100, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Vin', index: 'Vin', sorttype: 'text', width: 140, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Year', index: 'Year', sorttype: 'int', width: 50, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Make', index: 'Make', sorttype: 'text', width: 80, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Model', index: 'Model', sorttype: 'text', width: 80, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Trim', index: 'Trim', sorttype: 'text', width: 100, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       { name: 'Mileage', index: 'Mileage', sorttype: 'int', width: 60, align: 'center', formatter: 'number', formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:'',thousandsSeparator:',',decimalPlaces:0,defaultValue:'0'} },
                       { name: 'PurchasePrice', index: 'PurchasePrice', sorttype: 'currency', width: 80, align: 'center', formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: {decimalSeparator:'.',thousandsSeparator:',',decimalPlaces:2,defaultValue:'0.00',prefix:'$',suffix:''} },
                       { name: 'StockDate', index: 'StockDate', sorttype: 'date', width: 80, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y' } },  //"formatter" and "formatoptions" is required for date sorting to works properly...
                       { name: 'RepairCost', index: 'RepairCost', sorttype: 'currency', width: 80, align: 'center', formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00', prefix: '$', suffix: '' } },
                       { name: 'TotalCost', index: 'TotalCost', sorttype: 'currency', width: 80, align: 'center', formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '0.00', prefix: '$', suffix: '' } },
                       { name: 'DaysInInventory', index: 'DaysInInventory', sorttype: 'int', width: 65, align: 'center', formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 0, defaultValue: '1' } },
                       { name: 'InventoryTrackerLocationId', index: 'InventoryTrackerLocationId', sorttype: 'int', width: 0, align: 'left', hidden: true, hidedlg: true },  //"hidedlg" is use to hide the hidden column in "Column Chooser"...
                       { name: 'InventoryTrackerLocation', index: 'InventoryTrackerLocation', sorttype: 'text', width: 120, align: 'center', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne'] } },
                       //Links is not present in json data from the website, so we customize it here...
                       { name: 'Links', index: 'Links', sorttype: 'text', width: 80, align: 'center', formatter: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) { return "<span style='text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;'>Links</span>" }, search: false }  //"search" is use to hide the field in search dialog...
            ],
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                if (this.p.colModel[$.jgrid.getCellIndex($(e.target).closest("td")[0])].name === jqgridColumnNameLinks) {
                    jqgridPopupDialogLinkOptions(
                        $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCell(rowid, jqgridColumnIdStockNumber),
                        $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCell(rowid, jqgridColumnIdVin),
                        $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCell(rowid, jqgridColumnIdInventoryTrackerLocationId)
                    );
                    return false;
                }
            },
            pager: '#'+jqgridPagerId,
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],  //Drop-down selection in footer - To show how many rows per page...
            //This "sortname"/"sortorder" must be specified for "getGridParam"'s 'datatype'/'sortname'/'sortorder' (column sorting) to work.  (Some kind of jqGrid bug or feature which we need to hack to do a workaround with)...
            <% if(postQuickQuoteSalePrice.Length > 0) { %>
            sortname: 'TotalCost', sortorder: 'desc',  //Coming from Quick-Quote webpage...
            <% }else{ %>
            sortname: 'StockDate', sortorder: 'desc',  //Coming from any webpages...
            <% } %>
            viewrecords: true,
            //gridview: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'My Inventory',
            width: 1022,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            height: 400,
            sortable: true,  /* This allows both 1) Moving columns sideway to other location fields and 2) for jqGrid Column Chooser Plugin / JQuery Multiselect Plugin to work... */
            grouping: true,  /* This allows row data to be group into row grouping... */
            loadonce: true,  //In this case, use "sorttype" property in "colModel" for it to work when "loadonce" is set to true...
            emptyrecords: "No records to display",
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                alert("An error had occurred, please try again or notify webmaster of this error");
            },
            loadComplete: function () {
                var $self = $(this);  //This is needed to seperate itself from binding jqGrid or $(this) objects for it to work.  It wouldn't work without it...
                if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'datatype') === 'json') {  //This the value when loading webpage then the value of "datatype" option will become "local" afterward...
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $self.triggerHandler("reloadGrid");
                    }, 50);
                }
                //jqgridSummarySpreadsheetDisplay();
            }
        });

        //jqGrid - My-Inventory-Summary...
        function jqgridSummarySpreadsheetDisplay() {
            $('#' + jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId).setCell(1, 'TotalVehicles', ($('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getGridParam('records')), {'vertical-align':'middle'}, '', '');  //getGridParam('data').length)
            $('#' + jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId).setCell(1, 'TotalPurchaseCost', ($('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCol('PurchasePrice', false, 'sum')), { 'vertical-align': 'middle' }, '', '');
            $('#' + jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId).setCell(1, 'TotalRepairCost', ($('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCol('RepairCost', false, 'sum')), { 'vertical-align': 'middle' }, '', '');
            $('#' + jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId).setCell(1, 'TotalCost', ($('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).getCol('TotalCost', false, 'sum')), { 'vertical-align': 'middle' }, '', '');
        }

        //Navigation Buttons...
        //http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator...
        //http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_buttons...
        //This is required for "navButtonAdd" to appear...
        $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).navGrid('#'+jqgridPagerId,
            { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: false, refresh: false },  //Options...
            {}, //{edit}...
            {}, //{add}...
            {}, //{del}...
            {
                multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: false, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterSearch: true, searchOnEnter: true, showQuery: false, width: 550, caption: "Search Records",
                //overlay: 1,  //If overlay is set to 0, grid is disabled but if set to 1, grid is active and you can play with both search and grid at once.
                afterRedraw: function () {
                    //Notice: May sure the "rule" drop-down selection is set to "all" by default...
                    $("input.add-rule", this).button().val("Add Rule");
                    $("input.delete-rule", this).button().val("Remove Rule");
                    $("select.opsel", this).hide();
                }
            }, //{search}...
            {} //{view}...
        );
        //$('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).navSeparatorAdd('#'+jqgridPagerId, { sepclass: 'ui-separator', sepcontent: '' });  //Seperator bar icon...
        $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).navButtonAdd('#'+jqgridPagerId, {
            position: "first",
            caption: "",
            buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
            title: "Show Columns",
            //cursor: "pointer",  //This does not work...
            onClickButton: function () {
                //http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods&s[]=column&s[]=chooser...
                $(this).columnChooser({
                    title: "Show Columns",
                    width: 600,
                    done: function (perm) {
                        if (perm) { //"OK" button are clicked...
                            this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                        //} else { //"Cancel" button or "x" button are clicked...
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        //Columns Header Grouping...
        //[Drag a column]...
        $('tr.ui-jqgrid-labels th div').draggable({
            appendTo: 'body',
            helper: 'clone'
        });
        //[Drop a column]...
        $('#'+jqgridGroupColumnHeader+' ol').droppable({
            activeClass: 'ui-state-default',
            hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
            accept: ':not(.ui-sortable-helper)',
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.find('.placeholder').remove();
                var groupingColumn = $('<li></li>').attr('data-column', ui.draggable.attr('id').replace('jqgh_' + jqgridSpreadsheetId + '_', ''));
                $('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close"></span>').click(function () {
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    $('#' + jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingRemove');
                   $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', $('#'+jqgridGroupColumnHeader+' ol li:not(.placeholder)').map(function () { return $(this).attr('data-column'); }).get());
                    //Make the text re-appear after the very last column is removed...
                    if ($('#'+jqgridGroupColumnHeader+' ol li:not(.placeholder)').length === 0) {
                        $('<li class="placeholder">Drop header columns here</li>').appendTo($this);
                    }
                }).appendTo(groupingColumn);
                groupingColumn.append(ui.draggable.text());
                groupingColumn.appendTo($this);
                $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingRemove');
                $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', $('#'+jqgridGroupColumnHeader+' ol li:not(.placeholder)').map(function () { return $(this).attr('data-column'); }).get());
            }
        });
        //[Re-arrange columns' position in "Group Column Header" box]...
        $('#' + jqgridGroupColumnHeader + ' ol').sortable({
            items: 'li:not(.placeholder)',
            sort: function () {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-default');
            },
            stop: function () {
                $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingRemove');
                $('#'+jqgridSpreadsheetId).jqGrid('groupingGroupBy', $('#'+jqgridGroupColumnHeader+' ol li:not(.placeholder)').map(function () { return $(this).attr('data-column'); }).get());
            }
            , revert: true
        });

        //Reposition the GUI stuff on browser resizing...
        $(window).resize(function () {
            $('#' + jqgridDialogLinkOptions).dialog("option", "position", "center");
        });
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================

        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //My Inventory Summary...
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //jqGrid Plugin...
        $('#' + jqgridSummarySpreadsheetId).jqGrid({
            datatype: 'jsonstring',  //'local',
            datastr: [{ "id": 1, "cell": ["", "", "", ""] }],  //It is surprising that it accepted blank values...
            colNames: ['Total Vehicles', 'Total Purchase Cost', 'Total Repair Cost', 'Total Cost'],  //Display Text in Column Header...
            colModel: [
                       //In this case, use "sorttype" property in "colModel" for it to work when "loadonce" is set to true...
                       { name: 'TotalVehicles', index: 'TotalVehicles', sorttype: 'int', align: 'center',  sortable: false, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 0, defaultValue: '' } },
                       { name: 'TotalPurchaseCost', index: 'TotalPurchaseCost', sorttype: 'currency', align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '', prefix: '$', suffix: '' } },
                       { name: 'TotalRepairCost', index: 'TotalRepairCost', sorttype: 'currency', align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '', prefix: '$', suffix: '' } },
                       { name: 'TotalCost', index: 'TotalCost', sorttype: 'currency', align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'currency', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: '.', thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2, defaultValue: '', prefix: '$', suffix: '' } }
            ],
            caption: 'My Inventory Summary',
            width: 1022,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            height: '100%',
            loadonce: false,  //In this case, use "sorttype" property in "colModel" for it to work when "loadonce" is set to true...
            emptyrecords: "No records to display",
            loadError: function (xhr, st, err) {
                alert("An error had occurred, please try again or notify webmaster of this error");
            }
        });
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
        //=====================================================================================================================================================================================================
    });
</script> 

<div id="divWebLayout2" style="padding-top:2px;padding-bottom:20px;">
    <div id="MyInventoryJqgrid_GroupColumnHeader">
         <div class="ui-widget-content"><ol><li class="placeholder">Drop header columns here</li></ol></div>
         <div>
             <table id="MyInventoryJqgrid_Spreadsheet"></table>
             <div id="MyInventoryJqgrid_Pager" style="text-align:center;"></div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div id="divWebLayout3" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
    <table id="MyInventorySummaryJqgrid_Spreadsheet"></table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `loadonce: true` option. In the case the server (`'../websrvc/JqGrid.ashx'` in your case) should returns **sorted** data. It's the requirement of jqGrid. I posted to trirand [the suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/local-sorting-at-least-optional-of-the-data-loaded-with-loadoncetrue/) to change the behavior, but jqGrid still don't made any changes about sorting of the data loaded with `loadonce: true` option.

So to have the best results your ASHX code should get `sidx` and `sord` parameters (`context.Request["sidx"]`, `context.Request["sord"]`) and returns all rows of grid **sorted** by `sidx` corresponds to `sord` direction.

Only if you really have some implementation problem to make sorting on the server side you can do this on the client side. First of all you should set `sortname: 'StockDate'` and `sortorder: 'desc'` to values which corresponds to sorting results which you want to have. If you need to sort grid by `Year` column then you should use `sortname: 'Year'`. Then you should reload the grid once directly after the first loading. You can do this with the following `loadComplete`

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
        // the code will be executed only at the first loading because jqGrid
        // changes datatype to "local" after the first loading if we use
        // loadonce option. We use setTimeout to allows jqGrid to make the first
        // loading till the end and reload it AFTER that
        setTimeout(function () {
            $self.triggerHandler("reloadGrid");
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I develop since the end of 2014, has the option `forceClientSorting: true`, which can be combined with `loadonce: true`. The option force that sorting and filtering *on the client side* will be done on the first loading from the server. In other words, the option `forceClientSorting: true` replaces all the code described in the answer. On cause `forceClientSorting: true` works much quickly as reloading of grid inside of `loadComplete`.

Comment: Very interesting.  So it was the jqGrid's builtin feature that makes this useless until we implement a workaround to it for it to work.  (sort locally).  Thanks for your answer and help.  It works now and I updated the script above.

Comment: I saw the "the suggestion" link you provided and it seems to have died off from there.  :-(  I think eventually, it will happen in later version of jqGrid.  Is there a bug report in GitHub for this one that I can follow up on?

Comment: You got that right about implementation problem on server side which is why I'm doing it on client side.  There's no sql-query on webpage, it's all in repository dll file for certain reasons, plus minimizing sql-injection attack when possible.  Also, technology been moving toward object relational mapper [ORM] (or database objects).  Another issue, I can't sort the data when it comes to 1 million rows nor do I write IF-CASE-ELSE statement in ORDER-BY in MS-SQL.  It put us at the mercy of both MSSQL server, plus the seperation of web/data/server model and technology evolution.

Comment: @fletchsod: You are welcome! If you verify that `context.Request["sidx"]` is one from selected strings (column names which you use) then you do can sort without any sql-injection attack. If you would set index in SQL table for every sortable column then performance of sorting of 1 million rows could be good enough. If you really need to display table with 1 million rows then you **have to** implement server side filtering because no user will page over thousand of pages. If the user could set filter which results will be 10-100 rows then the user can read results.

Comment: That's true about retrieving partial rows instead of all rows.

Comment: @Oleg this is awesome!! Really helped me out of a jam! Oleg to the rescue once again :)

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! I'm glad that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Fairly straightforward, set the properties of the grid:
Ex:

```
        sortname: 'ColumnNameToSortOn',
        sortorder: "desc",
```

Comment: I tried that one w/ no luck.  Also, I need to be able to set it when coming from a few different webpages where sortname and sortorder are all different.

Comment: We're using jqGrid version 4.5.0 .  We're not using sorting on the server side but on the client side upon loading.

Answer (score 0):

Just setting sortname and sortorder doesn't work.
You need the setTimeout as well.
This has a drawback: scrolling wont work as it keeps rebuilding the grid it seems.
So you jump right on top of the grid again.