# Programmatically Local Sorting on Server Data jqGrid

Tags: jquery, sorting, jqgrid, client-side

I have a server-side data bound jqGrid. I just want local sorting when the sorting-button is clicked.

I have done this:
Just edited: getting full data and then sorting and inserting it in the grid.

**Edited**

```
var asc = true;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("span.s-ico").click(function () {

        var allData = jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
    if (asc == true) {
        allData.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.myID> b.myID) return -1;
            else return 1;
        });
        asc = false;
    }
    else {
        allData.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.myID> b.myID) return 1;
            else return -1;
        });
        asc = true;
    }

    var alt = $.extend(true, [], allData);

    //alt.shift().shift();
    $('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: null, datatype: 'local' });
    $('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: alt });
    $('#myGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");
    return false;;
      //alert("I'm clicked");
    });

});
```

on a jqGrid which is configured like this:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: URL,
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: req,
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
        colNames: ['AnotherColumn', 'myID'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'AnotherColumn', index: 'AnotherColumn', width: 105, sortable: false, editable: true },
                    { name: 'myID', index: 'myID', sortable: true, width: 185, editable: true }
                ],
        rowNum: 100,
        rowList: [],      
        pgbuttons: false,
        pgtext: "Page {0} of {1}",
        pgtext: null,
        pager: '#myGridPager',
        sortname: 'myID',
        viewrecords: false,
        sortorder: 'asc',
        sortable: true
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all if you want sort or search/filter grid data *locally* you have to use the values of `index` properties in all items of `colModel` *the same* as the value of `name` properties. I recommned you just remove `index` properties from the column definition. Currently you use

```
{ name: 'AnotherColumn', index: 'Id', ...}
```

which is wrong.

You have many other important problems.

If you want sort *local* data then you have to *fill* first the local data. jqGrid supports `data` and internal `_index` options. Typically local data need be specified in the input option `data`. In the case jqGrid *sort* the data locally during building of the grid and then displays the first page of the data. If you use `datatype: 'json'` **and** `loadonce: true` then internal `data` parameter will be filled during filling of the displayed page of the grid. The input data can contains more as one page.

If you use `datatype: 'json'` **without** `loadonce: true` option then no `data` will be filled. So after changing of `datatype` to `'local'` the empty `data` will be source for the grid and the sorting with `sortGrid` method will follow calling of `populate` method which just reloads the grid. In case of  `datatype: 'local'` and empty `data` you will have empty grid.

To tell the trust I don't understand your exact requirements. If you have not so much total date which could be displayed in the grid (for example less as 1000 rows) you can just use `loadonce: true` option and returns **all data** from `URL`. The data need be initially sorted or you can use the trick described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16648070/315935) for example. If you have really large set of data (for example grater as 10000 rows) you have to implement *server side* sorting and paging of data. Sorting of small part (one page) of data could follow to misunderstanding of users who uses the grid.

In any way I recommend you to add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true` options to the grid.

Comment: I have edited my code to make index and name similar.
Actually I can't use `loadonce: true`. I have implemented other customized button and if I make `loadonce: true` they are fully breaking themselves.

Thanks for explaining how sorting works! But any way to make `loadonce: false` and load data from server and as well as filling up the data field. 
If I initially make `loadonce: true` and then I make `loadonce: false` after the first grid reload and delete some rows. Then old data is also showing. Any way to solve it?

Comment: @soham.m17: How many rows you have? 100, 1000, 100000, ...? Why you don't use just the standard way `loadonce: true`?

Comment: @soham.m17: You can fill `data` manually of cause, but you need first *be sure that it's correct* way. You can fill `data` inside of `loadComplete` or `beforeProcessing`. The main question for me is now: whether it will be correct way?

Comment: I have around 100-200 rows. If I fill data manually after in `loadComplete` then if I edit or delete some row then apart from server `POST`, I've to update local data also. Right?
Anyway how to fill and update `data`?

Comment: just edited some code. but still it doesn't work. It sorts the data for the first time. But then no sorting is performed on descending order. Any comment on that?

Comment: @soham.m17: It means that you probably fill the grid in a wrong way. Could you provide test JSON response which can be used to reproduce the problem? You can use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler), Firebug etc to get the exact server response. Do you work now with `loadonce: true`? Which is the current JavaScript code which you use?

Comment: Here, I've used a prototype so it would not be fare to give any JSON response from the code actually I'm using at my end. I am not using `loadonce: true`. Still after executing `$('#myGrid').trigger("reloadGrid");` this line, it goes to `gridComplete` function defined by me and it doesn't sort the data according to my `alt`. I was wrong last time. It doesn't even sort the data for the first time following `alt`. It just uses increasing order `asc`. I am pretty confused how it gets `asc` order even if `alt` is in descending order.

Comment: @soham.m17: You fill `data` in a wrong way. Usage it inside of `$("span.s-ico").click` is definitively wrong. Moreover by setting `$('#myGrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: alt });` you can *combine* previous `data` with the new one instead of replacing `data`. You don't need sort the data with `allData.sort` - jqGrid do it for you during reloading. I think that you go in **wrong direction**. I still don't understand why you not just use `loadonce: true`. You can implement any behavior which you need in the way. If you edit the data or need refresh it *from the server* it's easy to implement